# SSIS - Setting a Dataflow Derived Column value from a variable

Tags: ssis

I have an ID in a package variable that I need to add as a column (with each row having that package variablevalue) in a Dataflow.

Is there a way to do this with only the `Derived Column`?

I know I can using the `Derived Column` to make a new column and then set the value using a `Script Component`, but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: Add the derived column component to the dataflow, then add a row and use the variable as the source. You should see Variables/Columns in the upper-left of the designer.